# Underscore extend with dot.notation quotes are removed, How to get it with quotes?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Here is an example:

```
var one = {test: 'test'};
var two = {'test.test': 'test inside test'};

console.log(_.extend(one, two))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmnck67b/

The extended object will return `test.test: 'test inside test'` which is bad for me because I'm looking to use it for mongodb and I need to make sure it's `'test.test'` with quotes. Any way to return or super simple solution to add the quotes?

Comment: The quotes on line two mark `test.test` as a string. They are not part of the string. If you want quotes in your string, you shod write `var two = {"'test.test'": 'test inside test'};`

Comment: [`"'test.test'"` or `'\'test.test\''`](http://jsfiddle.net/nmnck67b/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the single-quote part of the string by using a double-quote around it or escaping a second inner-set of single quotes.

```
var two = {"'test.test'": 'test inside test'};
```

Or:

```
var two = {'\'test.test\'': 'test inside test'};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmnck67b/1/